# SoapUI: How to cast 0 as 'false'

Tags: xpath, groovy, soapui

I'm using SoapUI to test a WCF service. I have an XPath Match assertion in which the Declare is:

```
if (boolean(//a:IsClick/text()[1])) then //a:IsClick else ''
```

For the source XML, the node is

```
<a:IsClick>false</a:IsClick>
```

so the Declare section equates to 'false'.

The Expected box has this:

```
${#ResponseAsXml#(//CLICK[text()],'')}
```

and the XML (from a JDBC Test Step) is:

```
<CLICK>0</CLICK>
```

so the expected value is 0.

I need to have these two equate so my assertion will pass.  One way to do this would be to cast the Expected result from 0 to 'false'. How can I do that?  Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath the `boolean()` function returns a boolean for number, string, or node-set. In your case where you want to cast a number to a boolean, `boolean(0)` returns false, for the rest of numbers `boolean(n)` returns true. In the other hand `boolean()` of string returns false for `boolean('false')` or for `boolean('')` (empty string) for the rest of strings `boolean()` returns true. So your problem is that using `text()` you're getting the `'0'` as string instead of a number so when you try to cast `boolean('0')` you're getting true.

In your case if you've some XML result from your `JDBC Test Step` like:

```
<Results>
    <CLICK>0</CLICK>
</Results>
```

You can convert this `0` to false adding `boolean()` to your expression and also using `number()` function instead of `text()`. So to cast the 0 to false use:

`${#ResponseAsXml#(boolean(//CLICK[number()]))}`

instead of:

`${#ResponseAsXml#(//CLICK[text()],'')}`

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to turn this into a Groovy problem - a Groovy assertion.

Here is a visualization (see [documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Truth)):

```
def negIsClick = "false"
def negCLICK = "0"

def posIsClick = "true"
def posCLICK = "1"

// fake "cast" the text to boolean
assert !(negIsClick.equals("true") ?: false)
assert (posIsClick.equals("true") ?: false)

assert !negCLICK.toInteger()   // zero is false
assert posCLICK.toInteger()    // all other numbers are true

// note the exclamations everywhere
assert !(negIsClick.equals("true") ?: false) == !negCLICK.toInteger()
assert !(posIsClick.equals("true") ?: false) == !posCLICK.toInteger()
// this fails
assert (negIsClick.equals("true") ?: false) == negCLICK.toInteger()
```

The last one fails, because you cannot compare a boolean to an integer. But in the cases before that, the `!` first casts everything to booleans.

So in your case, you will need to do something like:

```
// read in the two values
def IsClick = context.expand( '${XML test step#Response//*:IsClick}' )
def CLICK = context.expand( '${JDBC test step#ResponseAsXml//*:CLICK}' )
// now compare them
assert !(IsClick.equals("true") ?: false) == !CLICK.toInteger()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assert  '1'.toInteger().asBoolean()
assert !'0'.toInteger().asBoolean()
```